# cypher query to generate special path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like this

```
   O
   |
   A
   |
   B 
  / \
 C   E
/     \ 
D      F
```

I want to find the path from O to F. node F can contain an attribute call "non-direct". If this attribute is set false, then the path is

O-A-B-E-F

However, if it is set to true, the path is

O-A-B-C-D-C-B-E-F

I.e., the path first has to reach B which is a terminal node and then go back to the common parent between D and F, then walk to F.

How can I create a query to return these two path based on the attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

Since Neo4j will not traverse back over the same relationship, you may need to create relationships in both direction on the branches. So something like this:

[image]

In addition, I would add some properties that indicate the toplogy, so for instance add a property  `on-branch` for the nodes C and D.

Then you can run queries like this:

```
MATCH (f:Thing {name:'F'}), (o:Thing {name:'O'}), (d:Thing {name:'D'})

MATCH p = (o)-[:NEXT*]->(f)
WHERE ANY(node IN nodes(p) WHERE node.`on-branch`) = f.`non-direct`
      AND (d IN nodes(p)) = f.`non-direct`
RETURN REDUCE(s='', node IN nodes(p) | s+ ' '+ node.name) AS nodes
```

The graph I tried this on can be created from this json:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "labels": [
                "Thing"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "O",
                "on-branch": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "labels": [
                "Thing"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "A",
                "on-branch": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "labels": [
                "Thing"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "B",
                "on-branch": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "labels": [
                "Thing"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "C",
                "on-branch": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "labels": [
                "Thing"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "D",
                "on-branch": true
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "labels": [
                "Thing"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "E",
                "on-branch": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "labels": [
                "Thing"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "F",
                "non-direct": false,
                "on-branch": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "relations": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "source": 0,
            "target": 1,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "source": 1,
            "target": 2,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "source": 3,
            "target": 2,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "source": 2,
            "target": 3,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "source": 4,
            "target": 3,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "source": 3,
            "target": 4,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "source": 2,
            "target": 5,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "source": 5,
            "target": 6,
            "type": "NEXT",
            "properties": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

The json above can be loaded with this cypher (in Neo4j with apoc):

```
CALL apoc.load.json([ url to the json]) YIELD value AS v
UNWIND v.nodes AS node
CALL apoc.merge.node(
        node.labels,
        { _tempID : node.id},
        node.properties,
        {}
   ) YIELD node AS n
WITH DISTINCT v
UNWIND v.relations AS rel
MATCH (from {_tempID: rel.source})
MATCH (to {_tempID: rel.target})
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(
        from,
        rel.type,
        {},
        rel.properties,
        to,
        {}
   ) YIELD rel AS r
WITH DISTINCT v
MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n._tempID)
REMOVE n._tempID
```

Comment: what do you think about if i created two queries, first go from O to D, then D to F?

Comment: How did you insert this json file? I use `call apoc.load.json("file://path.json") yield value as v
merge (n:NEXT {id: v.id})
set n.source = v.source,
    n.target = v.target` but it says `Cannot merge node using null property value for name`

Comment: @drdot i added the cypher to load the json

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive solution. I loaded the json. What does your query supposed to return? I am not getting any return results.